# Importing View from xaml file into axml file in Xamarin VS2015

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to build my very first android app using Xamarin plugin on Visual Studio VS2015.

I already have the app on Windows. So I am trying to port the app.

I have the following structure for the App.

I have

```
MyApp.Portable (Portable)
```

-has

```
 View
 ViewModel
 DomainModel
 Common
```

-

```
MyApp.Android
```

-has

```
View
ViewModel
DomainModel
Common
```

I have copied over the `ViewModel`, `DomainModel` and `Common` from my Windows app and added it to `MyApp.Portable` and I am able to compile it.

I have added a very simple View to `MyApp.Portable` using Xamarin Forms (see below) using xaml.

I want to use that view (defined in xaml) file in `MyApp.Portable` from `MyApp.Android` `axml` file.

How do I do this?

Comment: That's not really how XF is intended to work.  I suggest you look at some of the XF sample apps on Xamarin's website for a better idea how they are structured.

Comment: @Can I use the same xaml file (that I already have for Windows) and somehow use that file for the view ?

Comment: No, the xaml syntax is different

Comment: @Jason - I thought Xamarin is supposed to be about interoperability. Apparently that doesn't apply to forms. Can I use axml on Windows tablet and Apple in addition to Android

Comment: yes you can if you use XForms approach

Comment: Xamarin allows you to run C# code on iOS and Android, and share that code with other .NET platforms via PCL or shared projects.  However, this approach requires separate UI/platform code for each platform you want to support.  Additionally, using XF will allow you to have a common UI layer across multiple (supported) platforms.  But it doesn't allow you to magically take a WPF project and run it on a mobile device, any more than than you can use ASP.NET to run WPF on the web.

Comment: finally, XAML and AXML are two completely different things.